# Lots of ram uses in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, ram

After latest update of `Ubuntu` I found out that it's using lots of `RAM`. I have `8 GB of ram` and from last week Ubuntu is using all of it.

I also use `Android studio` and after `2 hours`, my system `ram` is full and lots of `swap` is in use. Everything goes sluggish. I tried to optimize memory uses of `Android studio and Java` but still it's not helping. Following images show the status of my system after `45 minutes of use`. Now what exactly the way I can find the process which is responsible for this situation? I want report a bug but I need to find out the `problematic process` first.

## System

```
Ubuntu 16.04(64 bit)
Ram: 8 GB
kernel: 4.4.0-24-generic
```

According to `system monitor` I can see all process are using around `3.8 GB` of ram, where are the other process which are using other `3 GB` of ram?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try `sudo top` in a terminal. Then hit <kbd>></kbd> or <kbd><</kbd> until the `Mem` column is highlighted. The processes are then sorted by memory usage. Also, hit <kbd>c</kbd> to show the full command-line arguments of the processes.

You won't see root's applications in gnome-system-monitor. Most-likely, the other 3Gigs are used by root either for lightdm or another process - background stuff that *has* to run on your system for it to function.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of widespread problem. A bug has been reported, but developers not yet responded.

Follow the status of: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1572801

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using smemstat over a long period of time to capture the change in memory, for example, running smemstat to capture memory changes every 60 seconds for 120 minutes, use:

```
sudo smemstat 60 120 -o smemstat.json
```

smemstat will capture changes in memory and dump the data into a json file.

Hopefully that will provide some hint of what's eating memory over time.